# speechSynthesis not working on mobile Safari even though it's supported

Tags: javascript, mobile-safari, text-to-speech

Im trying to use the speechSynthesis API. It's working on desktop browsers and mobile Chrome but not mobile Safari.

```
  const msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance("Hello World");
  window.speechSynthesis.speak(msg);
```

I added a little test and it seems the API is supported on Safari, could it be a permissions issue that it's not working?

```
  if ("speechSynthesis" in window) {
    alert("yay");
  } else {
    alert("no");
  }
```

Comment: Is your 'speak' javascript attached to a user interaction?

Comment: @Frazer no it's based on a timer, however the user has already clicked a button to start the timer.

Comment: Can you add that bit of the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On my end the issue broke down to proper **loading** speech synthesis on mobile Safari.

There are some things to check in order:

- are voices loaded?
- are voices even installed on your system?
- is the utterance configured correctly?
- is the speak function called from within a user interaction event?

The following example summarizes these checks and works on MacOS desktop Browsers plus iOS Safari:

```js
let _speechSynth
let _voices
const _cache = {}

/**
 * retries until there have been voices loaded. No stopper flag included in this example. 
 * Note that this function assumes, that there are voices installed on the host system.
 */

function loadVoicesWhenAvailable (onComplete = () => {}) {
  _speechSynth = window.speechSynthesis
  const voices = _speechSynth.getVoices()

  if (voices.length !== 0) {
    _voices = voices
    onComplete()
  } else {
    return setTimeout(function () { loadVoicesWhenAvailable(onComplete) }, 100)
  }
}

/**
 * Returns the first found voice for a given language code.
 */

function getVoices (locale) {
  if (!_speechSynth) {
    throw new Error('Browser does not support speech synthesis')
  }
  if (_cache[locale]) return _cache[locale]

  _cache[locale] = _voices.filter(voice => voice.lang === locale)
  return _cache[locale]
}

/**
 * Speak a certain text 
 * @param locale the locale this voice requires
 * @param text the text to speak
 * @param onEnd callback if tts is finished
 */

function playByText (locale, text, onEnd) {
  const voices = getVoices(locale)

  // TODO load preference here, e.g. male / female etc.
  // TODO but for now we just use the first occurrence
  const utterance = new window.SpeechSynthesisUtterance()
  utterance.voice = voices[0]
  utterance.pitch = 1
  utterance.rate = 1
  utterance.voiceURI = 'native'
  utterance.volume = 1
  utterance.rate = 1
  utterance.pitch = 0.8
  utterance.text = text
  utterance.lang = locale

  if (onEnd) {
    utterance.onend = onEnd
  }

  _speechSynth.cancel() // cancel current speak, if any is running
  _speechSynth.speak(utterance)
}

// on document ready
loadVoicesWhenAvailable(function () {
 console.log("loaded") 
})

function speak () {
  setTimeout(() => playByText("en-US", "Hello, world"), 300)
}
```

```html
<button onclick="speak()">speak</button>
```

Details on the code are added as comments within the snippet.

Comment: This isnt working for me on mobile Safari or desktop Chrome.

Comment: Edited the snippet, which works for me on latest Chrome on MacOs Catalina and on the latest iOs Safari on my iPhone 7. I added a button, since `speechSynthesis.speak() without user activation is no longer allowed`

Answer (score 1):

It may just be a question of timing to get the voices, so if we request them when loading the page they'll be ready before the user clicks the Speak button.

I haven't put in any timeout to keep the example simple.

```js
if ( 'speechSynthesis' in window ) {
  speechSynthesis.cancel(); // removes anything 'stuck'
  speechSynthesis.getVoices();
  // Safari loads voices synchronously so now safe to enable
  speakBtn.disabled = false;
}

const speak = () => {
  const utter = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
  utter.text = textToSpeak.value || textToSpeak.placeholder;
  speechSynthesis.speak(utter);
};  

speakBtn.addEventListener('click', speak);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="textToSpeak" placeholder="1, 2, 3">
<button type="button" id="speakBtn" disabled>Speak</button>
```

This is a very basic example, not selecting the voice to be used or any language.

If this doesn't work there is another problem. Have you tested that the sound works on your device? Is the "[soft mute](https://talkrapp.com/speechSynthesis.html)" on?