# How to use SpeechSynthesis inside a setInterval function?

Tags: javascript, safari, setinterval, speech-synthesis, speechsynthesizer

I need a way to continuously use speech synthesis (like a word every 5 seconds) after the user has done an action like pressing a button.

But I can't create this behavior using `setInterval` on **Safari browsers**. This is my code, removing the `setInterval` function works fine. But enabling `setInterval` to work every 5 seconds fails.

[Code in codepen.io](https://codepen.io/360macky/pen/WNJgXyj?editors=1010)

```html
<button type="button" id="speakBtn" disabled>Speak</button>
```

```js
if ('speechSynthesis' in window) {
  speechSynthesis.cancel();
  speechSynthesis.getVoices();
  speakBtn.disabled = false;
}

const speak = () => {
  // Works without setInterval:
  setInterval(function () {
    const utter = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
    utter.text = "Hello world";
    speechSynthesis.speak(utter);
  }, 5000);
};

speakBtn.addEventListener('click', speak);
```

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61658740/speechsynthesis-not-working-on-mobile-safari-even-though-its-supported

Comment: Hi James, I come from there. I don't have the problem that in Safari it doesn't work. It works well. My problem is how to run voices continuously (setInterval) in Safari.

Comment: I can't make your example say anything on my macbook/safari, even if I take out the setInterval.  One of the examples on the linked question works, but only sometimes.  Sorry.

Comment: Hi James! I have copied the accepted answer from that link and put it in a Codepen.io ( https://codepen.io/360macky/pen/jOxvYjR?editors=1011 ), does it work for you in Safari? - I'm aware that SpeechSynthesis works strangely in Safari, sometimes I had to reload the page or browser.

Comment: Yes that one works

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep looking for an answer while I continue to see how I can make it work.